# desktop contact manager with access to gmail api?

Tags: gmail, contacts

I'm looking for a desktop application for Ubuntu that can handle my contacts from gmail.

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Open "Online Accounts" and connect your Google Account.

[image]